# Block events when have a div with greater z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css

[image]

DIV 1 has a `mouseover` event that shows DIV 2 and has `mouseleave` event that hide DIV 2, when DIV 2 is showed, how I can block DIV 1 events **when my pointer is over DIV 2**? `mouseleave` event now makes me Flickering]  (DIV 2 has greatest `z-index` than DIV 1)

Comment: Post a jsFiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Answer (score 1):

You can nest both divs and apply hover on parent:
CSS example:
http://liveweave.com/qtwQOE
edit : to reduce size of parent div to its content, change CSS layout display:
http://liveweave.com/94tdXW

Answer (score 0):

Are u expecting something like this[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HXUHS/1/)

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".red").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".yellow").show("slow");
  });
    $(".red").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".yellow").hide("slow");
  });
});
```